# Flutter pdf package footer placement

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, footer

I am having a problem with my footer with the `pdf` package in flutter. What I want to achieve is I want to place the footer at the top of the last page if the `footerContent()` is the only widget in the last page. And if not, for example, the table content expands until the 2nd page but not covering the whole page, the `footerContent()` will be at the bottom of that last page which I succeed at doing by enclosing it to `Expanded` and then `Container` and set the `alignment` to `bottomCenter`.

However I cannot think of a way to determine if the `footerContent()` is the only widget in the page. I tried the `doc.document.pdfPageList.pages.last.contents.length`, but the value is always 1 and I checked the 1st page which has multiple content and it is still 1 value. I don't know how to know and how to do the results that I want.

This is the `doc.addPage` part of the code:

```
final doc = pw.Document();

doc.addPage(
      pw.MultiPage(
        build: (context) => [
          _buildHeader(context, mode),
          _contentHeader(context),
          _contentTable(context),
          pw.SizedBox(height: CustomSpacing.medium),
          pw.Expanded(
              child: pw.Container(
            alignment: pw.Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: _footerContent(context),
          )),
        ],
      ),
    );
```